# Filtering a ListView of objects with a Spinner by a value within the object for Android

Tags: java, android, listview, spinner, categories

Hello in my project I have made an object class called "Program" with many values such as one, an array called "Category." All the programs are displayed by a `ListView` and have a set category `Spinner` in the layout (with the purpose of categorizing the programs with the matching categories).

I have this piece of code:

```
final ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_spinner, MainActivity.categories); //MainActivity.categories is an array filled with strings

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        listAdapter.getFilter().filter(text);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Program.java

```
public class Program {

    public String programName;
    public ArrayList<String> categories;

     .....

    public ArrayList<String> getCategories () {
        return categories;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return programName;
    }
}
```

But this only filters according to the text on the list, how can I get it to filter it by the `Category` variable in the list of Programs?

Comment: You need to show more, Program class Category class and also how you populate the spinner. The way U would do it is by filtering by category almost the same way as with the text. Until I see more is hard to give a proper solution.

Comment: @AndreiT I just edited the post adding more code. I don't believe filtering a variable is the same as filtering the text because that filter method is only prompted to the text

Comment: Please give an example of how you want to filter by Category. Because I am not so sure I understood what you want to achieve.

Comment: @AndreiT each item in the listview is a program, each program has a category (sometimes a couple) and I have a spinner in the layout filled with strings, i want to be able to filter out the list when picking an item in the spinner and then only shows the list of items that contains what the selected item of the spinner from within the object Program which contains a set variable which is a specific category.

Comment: In short you want to filter out(remove/hide) the programs that do not have the text in their list of categories, right?

Comment: `this only filters according to the text on the list`. No that does not filter anything. You should show your filter code.

Comment: @greenapps What are you talking about? The filter code is in the onItemSelected method

Comment: There is no filter code there. Only a call to a filter function. You should show the code of that function.

Comment: @greenapps That's within android's libraries, I didn't make that filter function

Comment: Ok. Than make your own. Overwrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

First take a look here and understand a bit about filtering:

[Adapter filtering android](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html)

Next, I think in your case you have to do the following:

```
@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
     FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
    // We implement here the filter logic
    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
        // No filter implemented we return all the list
         results.values = yourList;
         results.count = yourList.size();
    }
    else {
    // We perform filtering operation
    List<Program> finalList = new ArrayList<Program>();
    //here think of something regarding the upper and lower cases.
    for (Program p : yourList) {            
        if(p.getCategories().
              contains(constraint.toString()))
         finalList.add(p);
    }

     results.values = finalList;
     results.count =  finalList.size();
   }
   return results;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it should work. Where should I put this? Should I make an ArrayAdapter class?

Comment: Thanks for helping me but I'm trying to use the code you gave me and using the reference and I'm still getting errors else where. I created a new Adapter class and extended it ArrayAdapter and Its still crashing. can you show me how my customAdapter class should look like?